# Insertar elemento select dinámicamente con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo un problema al intentar agregar mas campos de tipo `select` en un `form` que tengo estructurado, el código de la columna es el siguiente:

```
 <div class="col s4">
    <div id="diametros">
        <li class="input-field">
            <select name="diametro_val1" id="diametro_val_1" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Escoge un diámetro</option>
                <option value="1">1/2"</option>
                <option value="2">3/4"</option>
                <option value="3">1"</option>
                <option value="4">1 1/4"</option>
                <option value="5">1 1/2"</option>
                <option value="6">1 3/4"</option>
            </select>
            <label>&Oslash1</label>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

En la interfaz se ve así:

[image: Interfaz1]

Hasta ahí todo bien, sin embargo, la idea es que al darle clic al botón azul se agregue otro `select` **idéntico** únicamente cambiando el id y name por su consecutivo correspondiente(`diametro_val_1`, `diametro_val_2`, `diametro_val_3`, etc), pasa que no logró hacer que se cree, he intentado de varias maneras, sin embargo solo crea el `label` ignorando el elemento de `select`.

El código de JavaScript de mi función es el siguiente:

```
function agregarCargaFriccion(){
    if(b < maxFields){
        b++;
        let select = document.createElement('li');
        select.setAttribute('class', 'input-field');
        let sel_tex = '<li class="input-field"> <select name="diametro_val'+b+'" id="diametro_val_'+b+'"><option value="" disabled selected>Escoge un diámetro</option><option value="1">1/2"</option> </select> <label>&Oslash'+b+'</label> </li>';
        select.innerHTML = sel_tex;
        console.log(select);
        document.getElementById('diametros').appendChild(select);

    }else{
        swal.fire('No se pueden agregar mas campos', 'Solo se pueden tener 10 campos', 'warning');
    }
}
```

Despues de darle click al botón de agregar columna, solo se despliega de la siguiente manera:

[image: Interfaz2]

Se muestra únicamente el `label` y no el `select` como pretendo.

La idea es que se despliegue de la siguiente manera:

[image: InterfazPrueba]

Así hasta el máximo (10), y que el usuario pueda crear uno por uno y eliminarlos.

*Nota 1: El contador de la variable `b` funciona de manera correcta, es decir, si agrega hasta los 10 campos máximos, por lo que el error no está en la primer validación (cabe mencionar que la agregué después de intentar corregir el error, ya pasaba desde antes).
*

*Nota 2: La última imagen de la interfaz (el ejemplo de como debería verse) fue maquetado copiando tal cual el `select` desde HTML, no fue hecho con JavaScript.*

Saludos.

Comment: Probé tu código en este [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nb8L6jvd/) y funciona correctamente. Estás 100% seguro de que el `select` no se está creando? Lo puedes confirmar con el inspector. Lo único que se me ocurre es que sea un problema con el CSS.

Comment: Este código que publicas funciona. Tiene algún detalle que cambiaría: añades li pero estás en una tabla, si usas lo li cambia la tabla por una lista  <ol> o <ul>. Luego estas volviendo a añadir <li> con sel_tex, quítalo y deja solo lo referente a select y label.  Mira a ver si tienes algún estilo o algo que lo deje oculto.

Comment: @Juan si, de hecho se me olvidó actualizar el codigo HTML para que concuerden los <li>, pasa que como forma de probar una alternativa a los <li> hice el cambio a <table>, en cuanto tenga oportunidad actualizo la el código de la pregunta para evitar confusiones. Así mismo reviso igualmente a ver si no hay un estilo o función de JS que oculte el select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder resolver el problema tuve que añadir `class="browser-default"` a los `select` insertados, al parecer internamente *MaterializeJS* crea otros elementos que permiten el funcionamiento del `select` estilizado, por lo que **probablemente** sería necesario usar el `append` de todos estos elementos dentro del JS en lugar de solo el `select`.

Es por esto que opté por utilizar una clase que el mismo *MaterializeJS* proporciona, el cual es `browser-default`, el único inconveniente es que no utiliza el estilo por defecto de la librería, si no el default de *HTML*.

Fue el único ajuste que fue requerido.

Saludos.